# Sonicwall DHCP timeout after AWS VPN tunnel

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services, dhcp, sonicwall

I have just setup an AWS VPC with a hardware VPN tunnel to our datacenter via a Sonicwall NSA 4600. Everything is working fine with the VPN between Amazon and our datacenter, but the DHCP has stopped working on the Sonicwall when the VPN tunnel is up. If I close the AWS tunnel the DHCP starts serving IP addresses immediately.

I've tried configuring the AWS VPN both as a tunnel and as site-to-site with the same results. I realize DHCP is layer 2 so I don't understand what the AWS tunnel has to do with this DHCP problem, but it seems to be directly related.

This is the error back from the vpn client: Status: 0x91103 (DHCP_TIMEOUT_OFFER)